# In GCC, how can I mute the '-fpermissive' warning?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, pragma

I am including a file from a third-party library that raises an error that can be downgraded to a warning with `-fpermissive`. But because I do not want to "pollute" my compilation log with these warnings, I want to completely disable this messages.

So far, I set the `-fpermissive` option with a [diagnostic pragma](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) when including the file; something like:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-fpermissive"

#include <third-party-file.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Since GCC usually provides both a "positive" and "negative" version of the `-f` flags, I thought about ignoring the "no-permissive" feature:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-fno-permissive"
#include <third-party-file.h>
```

But there does not seem to be a "negative" version of the `-fpermissive` flag (I am using GCC 4.6.3; but even the version 4.7.0 [does not have it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options)).

Can I mimic this behavior?

Comment: `-fno-permissive` is the default. `-fpermissive` and nothing are the "negative" and "positive" versions of the flag. That said, you should not use this. Fix the code! Even if it's not yours.

Comment: -fno-permissive is not the default, since the option does not exists. The behavior it would have if it did exist would be the default though. I could fix the code, but it seems more like a workaround... Anyway, fixing the entire set of included headers is not really an option.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant. `-fpermissive` is the hack/workaround here. What code are we talking about anyways. Maybe there's a better alternative.

Comment: I know I should not use the flag, but I must use the library; it's already deeply used: switching to an alternative is not an option. I guess that fixing the headers is ok then, given the context.

Comment: I've filed a regression bug in GCC for this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81787

Answer (score 20, accepted):

tldr: You cannot turn off the fpermissive output after GCC 4.7.

---

Just posting this here so it has more visibility: unfortunately, [zwol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932479/in-gcc-how-can-i-mute-the-fpermissive-warning/16555972#16555972) (while well-intentioned, and potentially helpful to those with older GCC versions) does not work for more recent versions of GCC. From GCC 4.8 and beyond, you cannot turn off the fpermissive output. [o11c in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932479/in-gcc-how-to-mute-the-fpermissive-warning#comment78167294_10932479) to the OP helpfully provides the following bug which tracks this:

*[Bug 81787. [5/6/7/8 Regression] #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-fpermissive" no longer](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81787)*

Note that it is in the state "RESOLVED INVALID", so the inability to turn it off is the expected behavior and there are no plans to change it.

Comment: Hmmph.  I'm not impressed with the argument for not making this possible to turn this off.  "Changes the meaning of the C++ language", "downgrades diagnostics about nonconformant code to warnings", bonnet blanc, blanc bonnet.

Comment: Even worse: GCC 6.2.0 requires the instantiation of a const version of a non-scalar out side the class declaration for the linker to be satisfied. This was resolved in C++17: not requiring the specific instantiation of the constexpr class static non-scalar. But it remains in the older compiler, which some of us are stuck with. And, for me, a crappy unresolvable situation.

Answer (score 14):

It's maybe a bit late for this, but one of these ought to do what you wanted:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-fpermissive"
```

or

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"
```

"ignored" is how you squelch a diagnostic entirely, and the inverse of `-fpermissive` is `-pedantic`, for historical reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you know where I can be find mentions about `-pedantic` being the inverse of `-fpermissive`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clearly documented.  You can read about `-fpermissive` here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fpermissive-154 and `-pedantic` here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-257  And if you read between the lines you might come to understand that what's going on is that the C++ compiler has `-pedantic-errors` as its default state.  But I can't prove that to you without pointing at the actual code...

Comment: ... and they don't have an online crossreference index for their VCS so I can't find the relevant bit of actual code without downloading it all and running a bunch of `grep`s, which I don't have time for this morning.  Sorry.

Comment: no problem, thanks anyway! I'll eventually try your solution see if it helps solve my problem.

Comment: What's the opposite of 'ignored'? (how to reinstate since I only want to do it for a section of code?)

Comment: @clearlight I don't know, sorry.  You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @clearlight: you can wrap it like so:

#pragma GCC diagnostic push  
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"  
// code that's generating the warning here  
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
(each of those statements on its own line obviously, sorry about the formatting)